# Alfresco notification mail link modify

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am using Alfresco community edition-5.1.x set up SMTP configuration in my production server whenever user doing activity in alfresco user get notifications mail, We able to get all the information but in the mail notification mail down alfresco url is there with my domain name (i.e http://mydomainxx.com:5038) when click the link not working browser because its wrong url how can i change to (http://mydomainxx.com) only domainname not with port number , I am stuck on that any can help out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the default alfresco-global.properties:

```
alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=http

share.context=share
share.host=127.0.0.1
share.port=8080
share.protocol=http
```

In your case just changing the port to **80** would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of places [mentioned here](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/urlserverpath-variable-12302009) that you could try out (haven't tried them myself). If that proves to not work, IMHO the easiest way is to simply change the notification FTL's with the URL you want (found at "**Company Home/Data Dictionary/Email Templates**").

However, it is not the cleanest one, so decide for yourself whether you want to take that route.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps someone.

```
#
# URL Parameters(SSL)
# -------------------------
alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=yourdomain.com
alfresco.port=443
alfresco.protocol=https

share.context=share
share.host=yourdomain.com
share.port=443
share.protocol=https


## Non-ssl
alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=yourdomain.com
alfresco.port=8080
#<YOUR_PORT_NUMBER>
alfresco.protocol=http

share.context=share
share.host=yourdomain.com
share.port=8080
#<YOUR_PORT_NUMBER>
share.protocol=http
```